# Access subclass' property from base class' constructor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I discovered something strange, which I didn't expect to work, actually works. I can access a subclass' (constant) property from the base class' constructor:

```
public abstract class Parent {

  public Parent() {
    var constName = ConstName;            // <-- surprisingly, this works  
    var randomName = RandomName;          // <-- surprisingly, this works  
  }

  public abstract string ConstName { get; }

  public abstract string RandomName { get; }

}


public class Child : Parent {

  public override string ConstName { get { return "Mike"; } }

  public override string RandomName { get { return new Random().Next().ToString(); } }

}
```

`Name` is a non-static *property* rather than field. I always thought a type's initializers (for `static` and `const` fields) were executed, then those of its base class, then the base ctor and then the subclass' ctor. *Which means that the child is not fully constructed yet while in the parent ctor.*

Is this "legal" C# which will work under all circumstances? Why does this work?

EDIT:

No it's not a dupe question. That one doesn't have the class schema in my question.

Comment: you have Name property inside Parent ! so technically this is legal & correct.

Comment: @Nikita Yes but child isn't yet constructed. Read the order of initialization in my question.

Comment: So you are saying when you debug & it goes to base construction , yu got Name as mike??

Comment: @Nikita Yes, it works.

Comment: Property compiles to method Get and Set so its like you are calling method with string return

Comment: It has to do nothing with const, it will considering the getter as a method.

Comment: @Nikita Why not? If it's "just" a method, then it cannot be called before the object is constructed.

Comment: What i meant is the getter is like a method that returns the value for the property

Comment: @Nikita Yes, but you aren't really addressing the question.

Comment: Run Code Analysis (FxCop), it will report warning https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182331.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking constructor of derived class execute before constructor of base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498927/invoking-constructor-of-derived-class-execute-before-constructor-of-base-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the abstract / virtual members of the subtypes. The property getters are methods in the end.

But.

As you said, the sub classes constructor had not been executed yet. Therefore, it may have side effects. That's why you get a warning from FxCop.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
  public Parent() 
  {
    // NullReferenceException here:
    var nameLength = Name.Length;
  }

  public abstract string Name { get; }

}

public class Child : Parent 
{
  private string name;

  public Child()
  {
    name = "My Name";
  }

  public override string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

Even worse:

```
public class Child : Parent 
{
  private string name;

  public Child()
  {
    name = "My Name";
  }

  public override string Name
  { 
    get 
    { 
      // NullReferenceException here.
      // You didn't expect that this code is executed before
      // the constructor was, did you?
      return name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1);
    } 
  }
}
```

Therefore it is not recommended to do.

Comment: Right. So I was correct to be surprised by this behavior, because it doesn't make sense. I suppose it was not easy to *prevent* this behavior, so the compiler team allowed it, but created the FxCop warning to tell you that it's a "very bad idea". Basically, this results in non-deterministic output!

Comment: I suppose my question could be thought of this way: just because something compiles, doesn't make it "right". There are bizarre edge cases which the compiler can't teach you. There's a lot of dark magic inside constructors :).

Comment: There may even be cases where it is useful. You can have properties, as yours, which return constants or have pure logic and do not access the objects state. You just need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Very true, it may be useful in some cases - as it was for me, which is why I stumbled onto this problem. But I'd rather err on the side of caution, because this wasn't a straightforward problem to unpack... imagine junior team members using/abusing compiler edge cases :-(.

Answer (score 4):

Parent has an abstract property Parent.Name. Because of the word abstract, you promise that instances of (subclasses of) Parent will implement property Name. if they don't, you can't create an object of it.

> Note that I say: instances cannot be created. If a subclass doesn't implement property Name, the class can exist, but you can't instantiate it.

Class Parent doesn't implement property Name, hence you can't instantiate Parent.

Class Child however implements Name, hence you can instantiate it, and because you promised that every object (=instantiation) of class Parent has a property Name, you can be sure that although all you know is that it is a Parent, you also know that it has a Name.

This is the basic principle of polymorphism in subtyping 
[Wikipedia about polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

It might be the main reason why you would want to subclass.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. You're referring to a compile-time contract, so you can be sure of the existence of the child property. But the point here, is that you are doing it before the child is (fully) constructed. That's what I don't understand?

Comment: On a second read, your answer basically explains (very well) the overall idea of polymorphism. But not the order of construction, which is at the heart of this question.

Comment: Because of abstract function, the constructor of Parent knows that the object that is to be constructed is a subclass of Parent. Although the construction of the subclass isnot finished yet, the subclass already fully exists. In every constructor, even if there is no base class you have to be cautious about the order in which you initialize the items of the object. You may call methods and properties, but make sure that they only use items that are already initialized.