# Control text update in event throws illegal cross thread exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, invalidoperationexception

I am working on a Youtube search by keyword programmatically and using Youtube API to do this. I want to fire an event when a search progress is completed and return the result in `YoutubeSearchCompletedEventArgs` sent by `YoutubeSearchCompleted`.

But the code in`YoutubeSearchCompleted` in `Form.cs` throws cross thread illegal operation exception. Normally, using `AsyncOperation.Post` method it must not throw `InvalidOperationException`. Because I used the same method in a download manager project before and it worked well. So I can't understand why this happens.

> Youtube search class

```
class YouTubeManager
{
    public delegate void YoutubeSearchCompletedEventHandler(object sender, YoutubeSearchCompletedEventArgs e);
    public event YoutubeSearchCompletedEventHandler YoutubeSearchCompleted;
    AsyncOperation aop = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);

    List<YoutubeVideo> SearchByKeyword(string keyword)
    {
        List<YoutubeVideo> videos = new List<YoutubeVideo>();

        //.......
        //...Youtube data api search codes....
        //.......

        return videos;
    }
    public void Search(string keyword)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            List<YoutubeVideo> list = SearchByKeyword(keyword);
            aop.Post(new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(delegate
            {
                if (YoutubeSearchCompleted != null)
                    YoutubeSearchCompleted(this, 
                        new YoutubeSearchCompletedEventArgs(keyword, list);
            }), null);
        });
    }
}
```

> Form.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    YouTubeManager yam = new YouTubeManager();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yam.YoutubeSearchCompleted += yam_YoutubeSearchCompleted;
        yam.Search("Blues");
    }

    void yam_YoutubeSearchCompleted(object sender, YoutubeSearchCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Videos.Count < 1) return;

        textBox1.Text = e.Videos[0].Title();
    }
}
```

In this code the `textBox1.Text = e.Videos[0].Title();` line throws `InvalidOperationException`. How can I fix this problem?

**Note:** I don't want `Invoke` method, just `AsyncOperation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the issue is caused by `AsyncOperation` created too early. You can check that with the following:

```
if (!(aop.SynchronizationContext is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext))
{
    // Oops - we have an issue
}
```

Why is that? The `AsyncOperation` stores the [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the construction time, and normally all `Control` derived classes (including the `Form`) install `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` from inside the `Control` class constructor.

But imagine the `Forgm1` is your startup form (e.g. the typical `Application.Run(new Form1());` call from `Main`). Since [Any instance variable initializers in the derived class are executed *before* the base class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498927/invoking-constructor-of-derived-class-execute-before-constructor-of-base-class), at the time `aop` variable is initialized (through `yam` field initializer), the `Control` class constructor has not been ran yet, hence the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is not installed, so the `AsynOperation` is initialized with the default `SynchronozationContext`, which implements `Post` by simply executing it on separate thread.

The fix is simple - don't use initializer, just define the field

```
YouTubeManager yam;
```

and move the initialization

```
yam = new YouTubeManager();
```

inside the form constructor or load event.